# Laptop CPU runs at 4GHz even when idle, while plugged in

Tags: windows-10, cpu-speed

When I use my Windows 10 laptop while plugged in, my CPU continuously runs at 4GHz, even when idle, causing the laptop to get hot and the fans to ramp up, but on battery power, the CPU's clock speed is regulated fine and it doesn't run at 4GHz continuous and overheat.

How can I get my CPU to run properly while charging?

I have tried editing power usage options (while plugged in) by left-clicking the battery icon, and I have set power plan to balanced.

Comment: Have you set your Power Management to High Performanced?

Comment: Power management is set to balanced.

Comment: @Mokubai Edited

Comment: @Mokubai Still not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the BIOS and check the CPU's C-States. You want them to be enabled in order to let the CPU "relax" under light workloads.

Since Windows doesn't have much control over your hardware (most of the time) these kinds of problems should be addressed directly at the BIOS level.

Comment: I do not have this option in the BIOS

Comment: what's your laptop's make and model?

Comment: HP ENVY 15-ep0500na

Comment: Have you tried resetting the BIOS to its factory defaults?